# multi type formatting in nim (boost format equivalent)

Tags: format, nim-lang

As an extensive past user of C++'s boost, I'd like to understand whether the nim equivalent `%` isn't under-powered compared to `boost::format(fmtstr) % args`.

I say that because boost::format works with templates and each argument is lexical cast-ed to string. But in nim the `%` proc works with an array of strings as an argument, so this doesn't build:

`echo "" % float(4.5)`

outputs:

> Error: type mismatch: got (string, float) but expected one of: proc
>   `%`(formatstr, a: string): string proc `%`(formatstr: string; a:
>   openArray[string]): string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `%` you can use `format` which supports all types and automatically converts them to strings: https://nim-lang.org/docs/strutils.html#format,string,varargs[string,]

In the next release of Nim there will be a `strformat` library with more advanced formatting: https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/blob/devel/lib/pure/strformat.nim

There is also an older `strfmt` library: https://lyro.bitbucket.io/strfmt/